# How to note a calculated default value in OAS3

Tags: openapi

I'm updating my API spec (OAS 3.0.0), and am having trouble understanding how to properly model a "complex" default value.

In general, default values for parameters are scalar values (i.e. the field `offset` has a default value of `0`). But in the API I'm spec'ing, the default value is actually calculated based on other provided parameters.

For example, what if we take the [Pet model](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/examples/v3.0/petstore.yaml) from the example documentation, and decide that all animals need to be tagged. If the user of the API wants to supply a tag, great. If not, it will be equal to the name.

One possibility:

```
Pet:
  required:
    - id
    - name
  properties:
    id:
      type: integer
      format: int64
    name:
      type: string
    tag:
      type: string
      default: '#/components/schemas/Pet/name'
```

This stores the path value as the default, but I'd like to have it explain that the default value will be calculated.

Bonus points if I can encode information from a parent schema.

Is the alternative to just describe the behavior in a description field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenAPI Specification [does not](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/554) [support](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1418) dynamic/conditional defaults. You can only document the behavior verbally in the `description`.

That said, you can use specification extensions (`x-...`) to add custom information to your definitions, like so:

```yaml
tag:
  type: string
  x-default: name
```

or

```yaml
tag:
  type: string
  x-default:
    propertyName: name

# or similar
```

and extend the tooling to support your custom extensions.